# Finding definite integral of a shifted function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

[Graph f(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Fa6.png)

Let's say I'm given a graph $f(x)$ as shown above where I know that $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ when $-2 < x < 2$,  and $f(x)=5$ everywhere else.

My question is what would I do if I am asked to find $\int_{-2}^{2} f(2x^2)\,dx$?

I apologise if the question seems badly presented (it's because I made it up myself). I was originally presented with [this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4DnN.png). I finally managed to get the correct answer for that question (d) but the method I used there confused me when I tried applying it to the question I created above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Note that $2x^2\in (-2,2)$ if and only if $-1<x<1$. Then, if $x\in(-1,1)$, it follows that $f(2x^2)=((2x^2)^2+1)$, otherwise $f(2x^2)=5$.
Now
$$\int_{-2}^{2} f(2x^2)\,dx=\int_{-2}^{-1} f(2x^2)\,dx+\int_{-1}^{1} f(2x^2)\,dx+\int_{1}^{2} f(2x^2)\,dx.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: so I should do $\int_{-2}^{-1} (5)dx + \int_{-1}^{1} (4x^4+1)dx + \int_{1}^{2} (5)dx$ I'm assuming?

Answer (score 0):

So first we want to note that $$f(2x^2)=\big(2x^2\big)^2+1=4x^4+1$$
Then the integral becomes
$$Q=\int_{-2}^{2}(4x^4+1)dx$$
Let's do this the antiderivative way. 
$$P(x)=\int(4x^4+1)dx=4\int x^4dx+\int dx\\P(x)=\frac4{5}x^5+x+C$$
Thus,
$$Q=P(2)-P(-2)\\Q=\frac4{5}\cdot2^5+2-\bigg(\frac4{5}(-2)^5-2\bigg)\\Q=\frac{276}{5}$$
And there you go.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\int_{-2}^2 f(2x^2) \, dx &= 2 \int_0^2 f(2x^2) \, dx\\
&= 2 \left(\int_0^{1} f(2x^2) \, dx + \int_1^2 f(2x^2) \, dx \right) \\
&= 2 \left(\int_0^{1} ((2x^2)^2+1) \, dx + \int_1^2 5 \, dx \right) \\
\end{align}

Hopefully you can take it from here.